# not able to use useRef hook when conditionally showing input fields

Tags: javascript, html, react-hooks

I have a requirement to display an input field and focus the element on click of a button my code snippet looks like this

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [enableSearch,setEnableSearch]=useState(false);

  const handleClick= () => {
    setEnableSearch(!enableSearch)
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div >
      {enableSearch&&<input ref={inputRef}/>}
      <button  onClick={handleClick}>show input</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am not able to get the cursor focus on the input when enableSearch condition is used what is wrong in this implementation?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, input field `is not rendered` because you have added conditional rendering. When you click on button , you changed value of `enableSearch`. As useState hook updater method  `behave like async` so it take may take few time and on next line you added   `inputRef.current.focus()`. Again, may be your input is not rendered yet therefore it not able to fine `inputRef` that is null and therefore you focus was not working.

Here is updated code snippet to add focus on button click

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [enableSearch, setEnableSearch] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setEnableSearch(!enableSearch);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (enableSearch) {
      inputRef.current?.focus();
    }
  }, [enableSearch]);
  return (
    <div>
      {enableSearch && <input ref={inputRef} />}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>show input</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating state in React is asynchronous, so react will wait until all the code in the event handler has run before processing the state update. ([docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#react-batches-state-updates))

That's why when you're trying to focus on the input, it will throw an error since the input doesn't exist yet.

You could use `useEffect` to change focus when the `enableSearch` value changes to true

```
export default function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [enableSearch, setEnableSearch] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (enableSearch) {
      inputRef.current?.focus();
    }
  }, [enableSearch])

  const handleClick = () => {
    setEnableSearch(!enableSearch);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {enableSearch && <input ref={inputRef} />}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>show input</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if that's all what you need that ref for, then you can do this:

```
import { useReducer } from "react";

const autoFocus = input => input?.focus();

function App() {
  const [enableSearch, toggleSearchInput] = useReducer(v => !v, false);

  return (
    <div >
      {enableSearch && <input ref={autoFocus} />}
      <button onClick={toggleSearchInput}>show input</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs